# Unable to Query the Deleted Records

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

I am able to see the deleted records in the Recycle Bin. But when we try to query the deleted records using the QueryAll/IsDeleted/AllRows keywords the query is not returning the records.

However, the query  `SELECT Id,IsDeleted,IsPrivate,OwnerId,ParentId FROM Note WHERE Id = '00X0903940'` is working fine for system admin profile .

However , It fails and give no records for the different profile. The record is still there inside the recycle bin

Comment: Is that your complete query? You need the `ALL ROWS` keyword...

Comment: Also, "normal users" can't query records that are deleted by someone else. Make sure that they were the ones that deleted the record(s).

Comment: @sfdcfox that is the one who has deleted the record .